# Interface an ultrasonic sensor with Z-Wave

Tags: sensors, iot, z-wave

The task at hand is to integrate/interface an already existing ultrasonic sensor like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-5V-Ultrasonic-Module-Distance-Measuring-Transducer-Sensor-Perfect-Waterproof-/271900302156) one to a Z-wave transceiver.

Here are the questions related to it:

1. Is it possible?
2. What all do I need for it? (Hardware + Software)
3. Are there any examples that i can follow?

Comment: Would love this myself as well. There is no already existing distance sensor for Z-Wave.

Answer (score 0):

If this sensor is Arduino compatible, you can have a look ar the [Z-Uno project](http://z-uno.z-wave.me/).

Their product is an Arduino compatible Z-Wave board, which you can program from Arduino IDE and use as a Z-Wave sensor/actor.

Comment: Z-Uno not available yet in North America.